# Ansible: Changing permission of a directory issue

Tags: java, ansible, chown

I'm running the following Ansible task to change permission of a directory and its content.

```
- name: Change ownership of everything below /opt/as2/app-server
  file: path=/opt/as2/app-server state=directory recurse=yes owner=adrt group=adrt
```

When running it I get the following issue:

> TASK [appserver : Change ownership of everything below /opt/as2/app-server] ****
>   fatal: [192.168.1.182]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UrBo6x/ansible_module_file.py\", line 451, in \r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UrBo6x/ansible_module_file.py\", line 335, in main\r\n    changed |= recursive_set_attributes(module, to_bytes(file_args['path'], errors='surrogate_or_strict'), follow, file_args)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UrBo6x/ansible_module_file.py\", line 146, in recursive_set_attributes\r\n    changed |= module.set_fs_attributes_if_different(tmp_file_args, changed)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UrBo6x/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 1163, in set_fs_attributes_if_different\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UrBo6x/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 929, in set_owner_if_different\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UrBo6x/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 842, in user_and_group\r\nOSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/as2/app-server-1.0.0/apps/station/WEB-INF/classes/org/adroitlogic/isuite/metrics/As2MetricsService/usr/bin/python$tt__collectStats_closure14.class'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}

Basically it says there is no such file or directory as,

```
/opt/as2/app-server-1.0.0/apps/station/WEB-INF/classes/org/adroitlogic/isuite/metrics/As2MetricsService/usr/bin/python$tt__collectStats_closure14.class
```

The content of the directory, `/opt/as2/app-server/apps/station/WEB-INF/classes/org/adroitlogic/isuite/metrics/` is,

```
As2MetricsService$_$tt__CountStatisticsLists_closure3.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure10.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure11.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure12.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure13.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure14.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure15.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure4.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure5.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure6.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure7.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure8.class
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure9.class
As2MetricsService$_CountStatisticsLists_closure1.class
As2MetricsService$_collectStats_closure2.class
As2MetricsService.class
```

There are no subdirectories.

Also when I run the command `chown -R adrt:adrt .` inside the directory `/opt/as2/app-server` it executes without any issue.

Help me to understand what is happening here.

Comment: unfortunately its not so obvious to me.

Comment: Are you going to submit an issue to GitHub?

Comment: Yes I was going to do that.

Comment: @techraf reported at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20496. Please let me know if it requires to be modified.

Comment: I'm not the one to decide what's good or bad, but since you ask... On a first glance I think you don't need to confuse readers with this long path. It fails even `./testdir/test$_$file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Help me to understand what is happening here.

You have just found a bug in Ansible which causes modules to fail when the names of files it processes contain `$_` sequence.

The name is passed without escaping the `$` character (or rather with an explicit conversion request [`os.path.expandvars(filename)`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L840)) and the sequence `$_` is processed as an built-in variable resolving to the path of the current process (`/usr/bin/python` in this case, as Ansible uses Python to run its modules).

In result the file name:

```
As2MetricsService$_$tt__collectStats_closure14.class
```

is interpreted as:

```
As2MetricsService/usr/bin/python$tt__collectStats_closure14.class
```

and the system throws an error that the file does not exist (which is true).

---

Until it is fixed, I guess you have to call `chown` with the `command` module